# Exclude a specific file from htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed in my root and its htaccess rewrite rules are preventing me from accessing `example.com/file.php` and instead redirects to `/`.

I want to exclude that one specific file from rewrite rules.

Existing htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(file\.php)
```

i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(file\.php) [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: try my editted answer. if that doesnt work - try chaning /index.php to index.php (i.e. remove the / )

Comment: No go. I moved the `file.php` line around in different orders, with and without the prepending `index.php` slash. Any other ideas?

Comment: another edit - try adding the [L]. If not - try removing everything except my last two lines, does that work? If so, slowly add each extra line back in, and see which line stops it.

Comment: `RewriteCond $1 !^(file\.php) [L]` throws a 500 on every URL. `RewriteCond $1 !^(file\.php)` isn't effective. I've tried just about every combination I can think of too. See why I hate htaccess?